# How to call CCButton on parent view from the child view

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In parent view, there's a CCButton called pausebutton, when click it, a child view will be added to this view

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
 pausebutton.selected = YES;
 pauseLayer *pauseLayer = [pauseLayer node];
 [self addChild:pauseLayer];
```

in child view pauseLayer, also has a ccbutton called resumebutton, when click it, this child view will be removed from parent view, and both set the pausebutton's selected is NO.

```
 - (void)backResume:(id)sender
 {
  [self.parent removeChild:self cleanup:YES];
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
 }
```

but i can't find a way to call the pausebutton from child view, so can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

On the parent class, add a method to force a pause :

in .h :

```
 -(void) forcePause;
```

in .m :

```
-(void) onButton:(id) sender {
    [self forcePause];
}

-(void) forcePause {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    pauseLayer *pauseLayer = [pauseLayer node];
    [self addChild:pauseLayer];
}
```

and in the child, when the condition to trigger a pause is met

```
[self.parent forcePause];
```

just the general idea, there are other ways to make this happen. This example would be for a very simple use-case/game. Alternately, in the parent you could be listening for a @"forcePause" notification and notify in the child.

Comment: thanks, but it seems wrong, it shows error with info `no visible @interface for 'CCNode' declares the selector 'forcePause'` when I call it in child layer `pauseLayer`.